# O(log n) quicksort complexity, is it possible?

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, logarithm, asymptotic-complexity

Could it happen that at certain values ​​of the pivot_value complexity of the quicksort is logarithmic ?

Comment: You can't even test if a list is sorted in less than O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The very first partition, regardless of the pivot value you pick, will take `O(n)` time - you need to compare every other element to the pivot.

After this you recurse and do the same for both partitions - the optimal choice of pivots (when each pivot is the median of the range) ends up with a complexity of `O(n log n)`. The worst choice of pivots (when each pivot is the largest or smallest value in the range) ends up with a complexity of `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Sorting using compare ops (and quick sort is such an algorithm) is proven to be `Omega(nlogn)` op - and thus it cannot be done better than `O(nlogn)` and definetly not at `O(logn)`

---

Sorting is `Omega(nlogn)` using compares because you need to use operators that have 2/3 possible results to manipulate the data. Since there are n! permutations for the data, it means you need `Omega(log(n!))` compare ops, and log(n!) is strictly bounded by `nlog(n)` - so sorting is `Omega(nlog(n))`

---

Note that quick sort can be done in `Theta(n)` **best case** by checking if the list is sorted and aborting if it is, but there is no case that can beat this, and definetly you cannot get to a logarithimic complexity for any case.

Comment: You may enjoy an O(n) solution [Quantum Bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort#Related_algorithms) :-)

Comment: I'm having trouble with my Quantum Bogosort implementation.  Can anyone demonstrate the "destroy the universe" step?  I can't seem to work it out.

Answer (score 1):

No.  In order for a sorting algorithm to be a correct algorithm (i.e. for every possible input it always produces the correct output) a comparison sorting algorithm like Quicksort MUST make at least n*log(n) comparison.  If it does not, then there is some input for which it cannot determine the correct output.  This is most easily visualized from the [decision tree model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_model), where each leaf corresponds to a correct output from the algorithm.

From the famous CLRS textbook p193:

> The length of the longest simple path from the root of a decision tree to any of
>   its reachable leaves represents the worst-case number of comparisons that the corresponding sorting algorithm performs. Consequently, the worst-case number of
>   comparisons for a given comparison sort algorithm equals the height of its decision
>   tree. A lower bound on the heights of all decision trees in which each permutation
>   appears as a reachable leaf is therefore a lower bound on the running time of any
>   comparison sort algorithm.

The height of the decision tree is n*log(n).

Answer (score 0):

No. The concept of complexity is detached from private cases, that's the whole point.

Comment: This claim is wrong. There is such thing as "**best case**"/"worst case"/"average case"/... analysis.

Comment: @amit My wording isn't the best, true. However, the question is obviously about a specific analysis, whether it's best/worst/average/whatever. The point is that the result depends only on the input size, not on a choice of pivot or any other parameter that is used by the algorithm

Answer (score 0):

No sorting algorithm can sort performing less than Ω(n) operations,
since the algorithm has to read the input. 
Here is a lowerbound using the adversary argument:

if an algorithm doesn't read a part of input then
we can change that part of the input without effecting the execution of the algorithm,
as a result we can change the answer but
the algorithm will not notice this change 
since it is not reading that part.

But quicksort does not achieve this lowerbound.
No comparison based algorithm can have 
worst-case (or even average-case) running time O(n).
All of them require Ω(n lg n) comparison operations. 
This can be shown using a decision tree lowerbound argument.

The best case complexity of the QuickSort algorithm
(which implies that the pivot is chosen optimally) 
is Ω(n lg n) as Dukeling has explained.

It is possible to modify algorithms and
hardcode the answer for a particular kind of inputs (like already sorted arrays)
more efficiently and potentially improve the best-case running time.
How efficiently depends on how fast 
we can check if the input belongs to one of those special cases and
how fast we can output the answer for those special cases.
We can check if an array is already sorted and output it in linear time.
So we can improve the best-case complexity of any sorting algorithm to O(n)
by hardcoding this special case.